# Grep messages for the last hour

Tags: bash, grep

I have an application which emits logs in this format:

```
00:00:10,799 ERROR [stderr] (http-prfilrjb08/10.1.29.34:8180-9)     {}:return code:  500
```

I would need to monitor for new ERRORs in the log file, happened in the last hour. Looking at some tutorials I've come up with the following grep:

```
 grep "^$(date -d -1 hour +'%H:%M:%S')" /space/log/server.log  | grep 'ERROR'
```

However nothing is grepped! Can you help me to fix it ?
Thanks!

Comment: I guess you need quotes after `-d` --> `date -d '-1 hour' +'%H:%M:%S'`. However, it would be good to have a proper [mcve].

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need quotes around the `-1 hour` and also you want to remove the seconds and minutes from the output (your current solution finds data only for the first second 1 hour ago):

```
grep "^$(date -d '-1 hour' +'%H')" /space/log/server.log  | grep 'ERROR'
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply! it works

Answer (score 3):

```
grep -E "^($(date -d '-1 hour' '+%H')|$(date '+%H')):[0-9]{2}:[0-9]{2}" /space/log/server.log | grep 'ERROR'
```

Let's take a look at the parts

`grep -E` tells grep to use extended regular expressions (so we don't need to escape all those brackets)

`date -d '-1 hour' '+%H'` prints the previous hour. Similarly `date '+%H'` prints the current hour. These need to be evaluated at runtime and captured in a capture group, that's why we have the `(date|date)` structure (you'll probably want some data not only from the previous hour, but the current running hour).

Next you need to specify that you are indeed looking at timestamps. We use `:` to delimit hours, minutes and seconds. A two-digit number group can be matched with the `[0-9]{2}` regexp (this is basically identical to `[0-9][0-9]` but shorter)

There you go.

Ps. I'd recommend sed.

Comment: Thank you too for your kind explanation